# Need understanding on Wireshark Capture from LSA update of a link.PCAP attached

Tags: ospf, wireshark

Consider OSPF in Area 0 is running on all routers and interfaces.
I advertise a route 223.0.0.1/24 from R4 in the diagram.
PCAP i shared is between r2 and r1 where R2 sends "LS Update"
I'm unable to understand the Contents of LSA Type 1 which has 5 links.
Please help me to understand why 40.0.0.0 is in that LSA update although it is being advertised earlier and there was convergence before the advertisment of 223.0.0.1 link?

and what are the Other links for in that Update

Here is a Topology given Below 
And PCAP is also given Below from Wire shark
[image: OSPF topology Used]

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlVb30iwW7P5qkWiMSC9wOdFmai5

Link is from One drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each interface state change a new Router-LSA is created containing the collected states of the router's interfaces.

According to RFC2328:

section 4.4

> ```
>   1      Router-LSAs        Originated by all routers.
>                               This LSA describes
>                               the collected states of the
>                               router's interfaces to an
>                               area. Flooded throughout a
>                               single area only.
> ```

section 12.4

> ```
>     (2) An interface's state changes (see Section 9.1).  This may
>         mean that it is necessary to produce a new instance of the
>         router-LSA.
> ```